# Stop crontab from filling syslog Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, cron, syslog, rsyslog

How can I prevent (certain cronjobs) from filling my syslog in Ubuntu 15.04?
I have some jobs that run 4 times a minute and quickly fill up my syslog files.

I've tried adding:

```
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
```

to /etc/rsyslog.conf, but this didn't resolve anything.

The current output is:

```
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25706]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 15; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server1//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25703]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 30; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server2//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25708]: (gijs) CMD (unison -batch /var/www ssh://server2//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25713]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 30; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server1//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25714]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 45; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server1//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25717]: (gijs) CMD (   unison -batch /var/www ssh:// server3//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25719]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 15; unison -batch /var/www ssh:// server3//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25690]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  8 06:58:01 elitegameservers CRON[25694]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  8 06:58:08 elitegameservers CRON[25588]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: What is it exactly that's being written to syslog?

Comment: Cron jobs running four times a minute?

Comment: I've added the current output.

Comment: Indeed, you should not delete and repost; this can cause your account to be automatically [rate limited](http://serverfault.com/help/asking-rate-limited) or even [banned](http://serverfault.com/help/question-bans) by the system, and moderators cannot do anything about either. I've done what I can to salvage this.

Comment: so if you add `>/dev/null 2>&1` after your command in crontab, does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding cron.none to the line that logs to syslog

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none,cron.none    -/var/log/syslog
```

EDIT: more detail:
From the ubuntu manpage for syslog
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/syslog.conf.5.html

> The special level ‘‘none’’ disables a particular facility.

The `*.*` at the beginning says send everything to the designated file. You can then qualify this after the `;` to stop specific messages being sent there. Here,we're saying that we don't want auth messages to be seen and now we don't want cron messages either.There's nothing to stop you putting cron messages somewhere else and the default file has several lines commented out to split up the logs in this way. All you have to do is un-comment them.

You can also limit the messages you get for a particular facility, by changing the level for example from cron.* which would log all messages, to cron.warn which would just log warning messages.

Thanks for the heads-up @peterh I'm new at this Linux community 
stuff.

Comment: Your answer got a "low quality" flag. It is because you only pasted a config line here, without a clear elaboration. I would suggest to complete your answer, fast.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you restarted `rsyslog`. As a result, you should then see your messages **twice** - once in `/var/log/syslog` and once in `/var/log/cron`.

So what you are missing is that after logging to `/var/log/cron`, processing should stop.

```
cron.* /var/log/cron
& stop
```

You can also configure filters to only log some messages somewhere else, or not at all - have a look at the [rsyslog filters manual](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/filters.html) for that.

Comment: I just added the & stop part on a new line like you suggested. But the entry's are still logged.

Comment: @gijs007 Do you actually have a file `/var/log/cron`? Or doesn't even that work?

Comment: Yes that file exists and looks normal. Although it gets way to large.